# Is there a name for this strange kind of matrix operation

Tags: linear-algebra

I've came up with solution to my problem that can be described as following:

For two square matrices $A$ and $B$ of size $n$ (that are considered an input to a problem) the resulting square matrix $C$ of size $n$ is created from scalar products of columns taken from matrix A, and rows taken from matrix B. I.e.

$C_{i,j} = A_{i,1..n} · B_{1..n,j}$

My question: Is there a name for such kind of matrix operation? I would like to know more about it's properties but I don't know what to look for?

Comment: Believe you will find that this is just AT * BT (T=transpose).

Comment: Could you write it with summation index? Your formula doesn't correspond to you description of the product in ordinary words, unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: Looks like you have just reversed the order of $A$ and $B$ in ordinary matrix multiplication. So $C=BA$.

Comment: `·` denotes to scalar product, so $A_{i,1..n}$ is a vector and $B_{1..n, j}$ is a vector and the result $C_{i,j}$ is just matrix element, so everything seems fine to me, or am I wrong? @Bernard

Comment: Except that scalar products generally want a row vector times a column vector instead of the other way around, although (at least in my usage) that may be relaxed for the product shown as a dot.

Comment: Ok, it seems that it is really just a matrix multiplication, I've yielded solution from solution from system of non-linear equations and it looked similar to matrix multiplication but wasn't obvious what is multiplied over what. Thanks everyone!

Comment: @Gandalf61 as a nit, I think you will find reversing the order of the multiplication only converts to a full matrix multiply if you are computing Cji rather than Cij, so that your product is CT.